# n-grams in R error: invalid 'times' argument

Tags: r, tm, rweka

I'm trying to follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15977288/1156245) but hit an error.

```
> library("RWeka")
> library("tm")
Loading required package: NLP
> data("crude")
> BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 2, max = 2))
> tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude, control = list(tokenize = BigramTokenizer))
Error in rep(seq_along(x), sapply(tflist, length)) : 
  invalid 'times' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In mclapply(unname(content(x)), termFreq, control) :
  scheduled core 1 encountered error in user code, all values of the job will be affected
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use some better/modern package. I can suggest several choices:

1. Use [text2vec](https://github.com/dselivanov/text2vec) instead of `tm`. See vignettes for examples. (I'm the author).
2. Worth to check [quanteda](https://github.com/kbenoit/quanteda)
3. If for some reason you like `tm`, try [tokenizers](https://github.com/lmullen/tokenizers) package to replace `RWeka` ngram tokenizer.

Comment: This is precisely what I'm after, and awesomely all at blistering C++ speeds!